# List orderId, Number of Order Items, and Total Order Price - not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I know the "not a GROUP BY expression" has been asked, but mine seems to be very different.

I'm trying to get a list of data from a view but I am getting the "not a GROUP BY expression" error.

**Code:**

`Select orderid, count(orderid) as Number_Of_Order_Items , count(orderid) * orderprice as Total_Order_Price
from orderdetail
Group by orderid
order by orderid`

Basically I am expecting to get the orderID, how many times that order ID appears and then multiply the number of times the orderID exists by the OrderPrice.

I have all of the non-aggregate clauses in my Group By, so what is happening here?

Comment: orderprice isn't being aggregated. so  you should use sum(orderprice) maybe..

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I didn't realize that. I did try Grouping by orderprice also but it was wrong, which is obvious now because I was missing SUM(). Thanks for your answer. If you put in an answer I can vote it.

Comment: What's `orderprice`? By its name, it doesn't make sense to multiply it by the count of items OR to add all the "orderprices" together. Is that in fact an ITEM price, that is the price of each ITEM in the order? Then indeed the sum makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sum()` on the price:

```
Select orderid, count(orderid) as Number_Of_Order_Items,
       sum(orderprice) as Total_Order_Price
from orderdetail
Group by orderid
order by orderid;
```

Note:  This assume that `orderprice` is really a separate price on each detail record that needs to be summed up.  In some cases, there might be a quantity column as well -- but then I would expect the column to be called something like productprice or unitprice.